# How to retrieve specific json data from http request using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to target the exchange rate from the JSON http response as listed below using jquery. Please assume jquery has been included in the withing `<head></head>` tags

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "XRP",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Ripples",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "GBP",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "British Pound Sterling",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.07367766",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2017-12-28 19:42:42",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="asset">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="BTC">Bitcon ($BTC)</option>
    <option value="BCH">Bitcon Cash ($BTH)</option>
    <option value="ETH">Ethereum ($ETH)</option>
    <option value="LTC">Litecoin ($LTC)</option>
    <option value="XRP">Ripple ($XRP)</option>

</select>

<div id="output" class="hide">


</div>
```

**JS**

```
var output = $("#output");
output.removeClass("hide");
output.hide();
$("#asset").on('change', function() {
  var coin = $("#asset").val();

 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
      url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=" + coin + "&to_currency=GBP&apikey=API_KEY_HERE",
      success: function(data) {
         output.html(JSON.stringify(data));

         // Would like to get the Exchange Rate only for use later on.
      }
  });

  output.slideDown(); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"]
```

```js
let jsonData = {
  "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
    "1. From_Currency Code": "XRP",
    "2. From_Currency Name": "Ripples",
    "3. To_Currency Code": "GBP",
    "4. To_Currency Name": "British Pound Sterling",
    "5. Exchange Rate": "1.07367766",
    "6. Last Refreshed": "2017-12-28 19:42:42",
    "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
  }
};

console.log( jsonData["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"] );
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

use the data object to select the bits you need, I've just added it to an alert in the example below:

```
var output = $("#output");
output.removeClass("hide");
output.hide();
$("#asset").on('change', function() {
    var coin = $("#asset").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/queryfunction=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=" + coin + "&to_currency=GBP&apikey=API_KEY_HERE",
        success: function(data) {

          var response = JSON.parse(data);

          alert(response['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']);

        }
    });

    output.slideDown(); 

});
```

Comment: Hi, after copying the above code the alert response seems to fail. Review answer from JasonB below/above. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.